# What is instagram api oauth2 and how to use it for login form?

Tags: php, api, oauth-2.0, instagram-api

There is task needs to be done for client, which requires login form using instagram api Oauth2, I don't know what is this and how to use this in login form?

Comment: simply how to create page with instagram oauth login?

Comment: Stackoverflow expects you to perform [a degree of research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/19068) **before** you ask a question (and to share the results of that research in the question). There are masses of tutorials on using OAuth2 out there. Please use your search engine of choice to find one.

Comment: Thank you @Quentin